# Moving from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10 - Migration Fails

Tags: iis-7, installation, coldfusion, adobe, upgrade

After having made several attempts to migrate from a ColdFusion 8 Standard server to a ColdFusion 10 Standard server, it feels like I am "almost" there.
I'm using the 64 bit installer from Adobe's website.

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 (64 bit) server with IIS 7.0.

The installation itself goes smooth and the services start and are running.
But at the end of the installation it says "ColdFusion Installed, but with errors" and it generates a log file.

The log file reads:

> Migration Error: : Check that "C:\ColdFusion8" is a valid directory and is an installation of either ColdFusion MX 6 or ColdFusionMX 7

and further down says:

> Status: WARNING
>
> Additional Notes: WARNING - Could not migrate settings from previous version of ColdFusion
>
> Custom Action:
>
> com.macromedia.ia.action.MigrateColdFusionAction
>
> Status: ERROR
>
> Additional Notes: ERROR - class com.macromedia.ia.action.MigrateColdFusionAction NonfatalInstallException null

The *applicationHost.config* file has new XML referencing the ColdFusion 10 directory, but IIS is still using ColdFusion 8. I'm also going to guess that the settings in the CF Administrator have not been migrated based on the message in the log above.

I've followed the instructions on Adobe's site, including ensuring that **ASP.NET**, **CGI**, **ISAPI Extensions**, and **ISAPI Filters** are all enabled. I've also enabled **IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility** even though I don't think it's needed.

Has anyone else had similar issues with ColdFusion 10 and IIS 7.
Currently I have uninstalled CF 10 and reverted back to

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is major change has been made in migration from CF8 to CF10.

Be careful and double check you DB Connections, there are new connectors provided in CF10.

The installation folder also may create issue.  The path for ColdFusion 8  folders is at  `c:/coldfusion8/lib` but the path for ColdFusion 10 works in different way to be `c:/coldfusion10/cfusion/lib` .

Answer (score 1):

I would perform a registry value search on 'C:\ColdFusion' using the regedit tool to see if there are some mapping oddities between CF versions and install file paths.  I would also look in the IIS management console settings to check the handler module mapping between the .cfm extension and the .dll (handler).  The fact that the installer is looking for a previous version 6 or 7 of CF installed to a directory with a path that suggests a version 8 install lives there just seems like a mapping issue to me.  Maybe there was a dirty uninstall of a version 6 or 7 that did not remove all of the registry settings before some were updated to reflect version 8 settings?

Comment: I'll look into these things and let you know what I discover. My current install of CF 8 was installed when the server was built, so it is not an upgrade from a previous version. I'll let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is the migration failing, perhaps skip the migration completely and just copy over your datasources from Coldfusion8/lib/neo-datasource.xml.

If you need your scheduled tasks too, I migrated from CF9 and that still failed, I just used the admin API and a script like this - to get them in. The other settings are negligible and I just configured them directly.

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:\your file here" variable="fileNeoCron">

<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#fileNeoCron#" output="wddxOut">

<cfset oCron = wddxOut[1]>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list="#ListSort(StructKeyList(oCron), "textnocase")#" index="sKey">
    <cfset oCurCronJob = oCron[sKey]>


    #oCurCronJob.task# - 

    <cftry>
        <cfif StructKeyExists(oCurCronJob, "end_time")>

            <cfschedule  action="update"
                         task="#oCurCronJob.task#" 
                         operation="httprequest"
                         url="#oCurCronJob.url#"
                         startdate="#dateformat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")#" 
                         starttime="#oCurCronJob.start_time#" 
                         endTime="#oCurCronJob.end_time#"
                         interval = "#oCurCronJob.interval#"
                         requestTimeOut = "600"> 
        <cfelse>

            <cfschedule  action="update"
                         task="#oCurCronJob.task#" 
                         operation="httprequest"
                         url="#oCurCronJob.url#"
                         startdate="#dateformat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")#" 
                         starttime="#oCurCronJob.start_time#" 
                         interval = "#oCurCronJob.interval#"
                         requestTimeOut = "600"> 
        </cfif>

        OK
        <cfcatch>
            ERROR <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>


</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error during installation however CF does not do the actual migration process until you load the CFIDE.  Bringing the CFIDE online after doing the upgrade process kicked off the actual upgrade process and migrated my settings.  Some settings however do not migrate from CF8 to CF10 correctly and will need to be manually migrated.  Scheduled tasks are one of those items.

Because of this I'm doing the setup in a coexist mode to start with and migrating the settings over to the CF10 server.  After that they have a nice GUI tool now to convert websites to use CF10.  However the flaw in the tool I've found is on IIS7/7.5 it does not remove the old CF8 references so you have to manually remove those.