# Coldfusion 10 migration error

Tags: coldfusion

After trying to upgrade from Coldfusion 8 to Coldfusion 10, I seem to be getting a migration error in the 64bit installer. It seems to be the exact same issue as [Moving from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10 - Migration Fails](https://serverfault.com/questions/410410/moving-from-coldfusion-8-to-coldfusion-10-migration-fails), but that question is out-of-date and with no reply from either the person who asked the question nor any answer that was marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just uninstalled ColdFusion 8 and installed ColdFusion 10 without migration, and manually configured CF again. It seems to work now fine.